# else if two lines instead of one line

Tags: java, if-statement

I just need to know that if you do an else if on two lines does it still perform the same as an else if on one line?

```
a bunch of ifs then.....

else if(somecondition here) {
//do some stuff here
}
```

does the below code perform the same as above?

```
else
  if(somecondition here) {
//do some stuff here
}
```

OR does it perform as an ELSE by itself then goes into the if after all else, like a normal else statement would.

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: There's not difference between the two snippets - Java does not use newlines for determining what source code means

Comment: Java doesn't have else-if. You only write an if inside of an else-block.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace doesn't matter in Java, as long as you have at least one. So the two snippets are equivalent.

Even if you write

```
else               if (...)
```

or

```
else 




if (...)
```

it will still be the same.

> OR does it perform as an ELSE by itself then goes into the if after all else, like a normal else statement would.

No, here the `if` statement is technically inside the `else` clause. If you want the above behaviour, try putting a `;` after `else`. This makes the `if` not part of the `else` clause.

```
if (...) {

} else; // note the semicolon
if (...) {

}
```

But you'll never write that anyway, you'll just remove the `else` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(somecondition here) {
//do some stuff here
}
```

and

```
else
  if(somecondition here) {
//do some stuff here
}
```

both are same. `Java doesn't use newline to determine new statement`

If you want the else to be itself and if to be in it you should change it to-

```
else {
    if(somecondition here) {
    //do some stuff here
    }
}
```

Technically it is same as `else if` in some cases